# Создание объектов в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему при создании объекта в void start создается бесконечное количество объектов?

```
public class creater : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;


    private void Start()
    {
      Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(2, 5, 15), Quaternion.Euler(10, 20, 30));
    }
}
```

Я так понимаю объект создает новый объект, а тот создает новый объект и так бесконечно? Но почему так? Ведь void start вызывается один раз. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя видимо префаб с этим скриптом. И один из них сразу на сцене. Логично, что  при инициализации префаб запускает метод Start и инициализирует новый.

Сделвй на сцене отдельно какой-то пустой объект и туда повесь скрипт с инициализацией префабов